# class selector won't work in IE8 pop-up window, but id selector will

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

i'm working on a simple pop-up window that contains only img elements. everything is working fine, but i ran into trouble using the class selector for the img elements. the trouble is that IE8 won't apply the styling (e.g., a simple border) to the img elements inside the pop-up if i use the class selector, however, it *will* apply the styling if i use an id selector. what am i missing? is anyone else getting the same results?

the javascript...

```
myWindow=window.open('','','width=450,height=800,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,resizable=no,directories=no,toolbar=no');

// prepare pop-up window with basic html structure
myWindow.document.open();   // maybe unnecessary
myWindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">');
myWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>'+popupTitle+'</title>');
myWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css"></script></head>');
myWindow.document.write('<body></body></html>');
myWindow.document.close();  // maybe unnecessary

var imgdiv = myWindow.document.createElement('div');
imgdiv.setAttribute('id','popupwindowdiv');
myWindow.document.body.appendChild(imgdiv);

// add image elements to the pop-up window
for ( var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var addImage = myWindow.document.createElement('img');
    addImage.setAttribute('src',<imgurl from images array>);
    addImage.setAttribute('id','popupwindowimage'); // WILL WORK
    //addImage.setAttribute('class','popupwindowimage'); // <-- WON'T WORK IN IE8
    imgdiv.appendChild(addImage);
}
if (window.focus){ myWindow.focus(); }
```

and the css...

```
// works
#popupwindowimage{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
// doesn't work
.popupwindowimage{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: `imgdiv.setAttribute('id','popupwindowdiv');` You're setting the id there, not the class.

Comment: Try to set `className` property instead of `class` attribute. Btw. `document.close()` really is needed, without it browsers show "busy" all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Teemu pointed out, use:

```
// add image elements to the pop-up window
for ( var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var addImage = myWindow.document.createElement('img');
    addImage.setAttribute('src',<imgurl from images array>);
    //addImage.setAttribute('id','popupwindowimage'); // WILL WORK
    //addImage.setAttribute('class','popupwindowimage'); // <-- WON'T WORK IN IE8
    addItem.className += "popupwindowimage"; // <-- SHOULD WORK IN ALL BROWSERS
    imgdiv.appendChild(addImage);
}
```

This should be the best option for you.

Comment: not sure why you used += instead of just =, but thanks to both you and Teemu it's working now.